# Are binary forms of composite degree of composite type?

Tags: polynomials

Let $F$ be a binary form of degree $m$ over an algebraically closed field. We say that $F$ is *of composite type* if there exists binary forms $G,A,B$ with $\deg A = \deg B \geq 2$ and $\deg G \geq 2$ such that $F(x,y) = G(A(x,y), B(x,y))$. It is obvious that if $m$ is prime, then $F$ cannot be of composite type, since $\deg F = \deg G \cdot \deg A$ and we have assumed both to be at least two.

It turns out that all binary forms of degree 4 are of composite type. Is this true for any larger composite number? If not, how does one prove that a binary form of composite degree is not of composite type?

Comment: That fails by a parameter count.  If $m$ equals $\ell n$, then the dimension of the space of equivalence classes of pairs $(A,B)$ of degree $n$ is $2n-2$.  The dimension of the vector space parameterizing $G$ is $\ell+1$.  So inside the vector space of dimension $m+1$ of binary forms of degree $m$, the set of composites has dimension at most $2n-2+\ell+1$.  If $\ell>1$ and $n>2$, then $m+1$ is larger than $2n-2+\ell+1$.  So $m=9$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Typo correction: the inequalities should be $n>1$ and $\ell>2$, not the other way around.  If $\ell$ equals $2$, then $m+1=2n+1$, and this equals $2n-2+(2+1)$.